Im asking for help for resolving an assertion error while building quickvina2 GPU2.1 on windows 11
Description of the issue
Im trying to setup quickvina2 GPU2.1 on my windows laptop. after finishing setting it up correctly, without errors nor warnings, i tried running it in visual studio as suggested, to perform the test run. I got an assertion error and everything stopped.
This is the first time i am setting up VINA GPU.
Steps to Reproduce

i cloned the repo

set up a C++ project on visual studio 2022 with the code

downloaded the boost library, bootstrapped it, and ran b2 toolset=msvc-14.3 variant=debug cxxstd=17 threading=multi

added in the C++ include dirs my quickvina2 GPU2.1 lib dir, openCL inc dir, my 12.3 CUDA toolkit include and lib/x64 dirs, the root boost dir, and the boost/stage/lib dir. in the linker additional libraries settings i put my boost/stage/lib and  CUDA toolkit lib/x64 dir. then in additional input in the linker i put the openCL lib file path, from inside my CUDA toolkit

set optimization for speed

set --config ./input_file_example/2bm2_config.txt as command arguments

tried to build but due to
Error   C1189   #error:  The <experimental/filesystem> header providing std::experimental::filesystem is deprecated by Microsoft and will be REMOVED. It is superseded by the C++17  header providing std::filesystem
I swapped experimental/filesystem for filesystem and ensured i was using C++17
i modified the
     std::experimental::filesystem::create_directory(out_dir);
     for (const auto& entry : std::experimental::filesystem::directory_iterator(ligand_directory)) {



snippet to use filesystem instead with
                    std::filesystem::create_directory(out_dir);
                    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(ligand_directory)) {


built and compiled without issues
ran from inside visual studio 2022

Expected Behavior
i expected the test run to go well without errors, and create the correct output in /test_out, instead it went like this
Actual Behavior
Using virtual screening mode
Output will be in the directory ./test_out
Reading input ... done.
Setting up the scoring function ... done.
Using heuristic search_depth
Analyzing the binding site ... done.
GPU OpenCL Platform: NVIDIA CUDA
GPU Device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Laptop GPU
Using random seed: 433324452
then an error pops up saying
debug assertion failed
program VINA.exe
file minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\app\stdio\fseek.cpp
Line 183
Expression: stream.valid()
press retry to debug the application
the line where the error happens is
_UCRT_VALIDATE_RETURN(ptd, stream.valid(), EINVAL, -1);

Environment
I am using

Windows 11 Home 23H2
msvc 14.3 in visual studio 2022
quickvina2 GPU2.1
Processor    13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13650HX   2.60 GHz
Installed RAM 32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
System type   64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
GPU nvidia geforce RTX 4060 laptop
CUDA 12.3

Additional Context
_UCRT_VALIDATE_RETURN(ptd, stream.valid(), EINVAL, -1);

in the code block
// Repositions the file pointer of a stream to the specified location, relative
// to 'whence', which can be SEEK_SET (the beginning of the file), SEEK_CUR (the
// current pointer position), or SEEK_END (the end of the file).  The offset may
// be negative.  Returns 0 on success; returns -1 and sets errno on failure.
static int __cdecl common_fseek(
    __crt_stdio_stream const stream,
    __int64            const offset,
    int                const whence,
    __crt_cached_ptd_host&   ptd
    ) throw()
{
    _UCRT_VALIDATE_RETURN(ptd, stream.valid(), EINVAL, -1);
    _UCRT_VALIDATE_RETURN(ptd, whence == SEEK_SET || whence == SEEK_CUR || whence == SEEK_END, EINVAL, -1);```

    int return_value = -1;

    _lock_file(stream.public_stream());
    __try
    {
        return_value = common_fseek_nolock(stream, offset, whence, ptd);
    }
    __finally
    {
        _unlock_file(stream.public_stream());
    }

    return return_value;
}

throws error
What other info can i give that will help resolving this issue?
Thanks

Is the tool supposed to work on Windows? That is relatyively rare, and most scientific tools are designed for *nix operating systems. The compilation instructions on https://github.com/QVina/QVina.github.io/blob/master/compilingQvina2.md seem to assume a POSIX shell, at least, and mention MacOS as an alternative but nothing else.

We have "linux" and "mac" dirs at https://github.com/QVina/qvina/tree/master/build but nothing else. I really doubt this is expected to compile and work on a Windows system.

@terdon
I am referring, as stated in the question, to the GPU version, specifically the quickvina2 GPU2.1 version, part of the vinaGPU2.1 repo found here
https://github.com/DeltaGroupNJUPT/Vina-GPU-2.1
which explicitly tells about windows compatibility as found in the
Compiling and Running
Windows
section
Thank you
